# Why is there a gap between the text 'crowded' and elements above it?

Tags: css, html

Why does this css code does not work correctly?

I don't know the how does this distance between 'crowded' and .pp appear.
what I expected is that the text 'crowded' can be extremely closed to the div.pp

```css
.pp {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: red;
}

.p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.flex {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp">
  <div class="p">
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
  </div>
</div>
crowded
```

[image: code and preview]

Comment: This seems to happen in Chrome but not in Firefox

Comment: `vertical-align: top;` to the inline-block element (not sure why, but related to baseline alignment)

Comment: yes,so strange,if i correct the div.flex 's display from 'flex' to others,it will be ok.(only flex and grid is incorrect)

Comment: You can accept one answer (if it helps you) by click on big gray check button on its left side. If you wish you can add +10 points to any author of any good answer by click upper gray triangle

Answer (score -1):

change `display: inline-block;` to `block` for  `.pp` class

```css
.pp {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: red;
}

.p {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: aquamarine;
}

.flex {  
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="pp">
  <div class="p"></div>
  <div class="flex"></div>
</div>
crowded
```